# Unable to Open any Terminal in Visual Studio Code -- failed to launch exit code 2

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

I recently installed **Visual Studio Code** and as soon as I try to run a terminal window I get this error

> The terminal process command 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe' failed to
>   launch (exit code: 2)

This also happens for PowerShell terminals

I have read many forums where this is asked and try the "solutions" mentioned there but none of that work.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was with the **antivirus** since it doesn´t allow a process (Visual Studio Code) to create/spawn a new process like the command prompt (Terminal)

To solve it make sure you **configure your antivirus to exclude Visual Studio Code** or stop all of the antivirus services --at you own risk--

To stop the **Symantec Endpoint Protection** use the following sequence of commands in a `.bat` file

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection
smc.exe -stop
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the machine has enough free memory. I had the same issue and it went away after closing some unnecessary application.